# My blender is stuck

Tags: modeling

I was following the lecture of LinkedIn learning and at this point it got stuck. I can pretty much do nothing but selecting the range of the object. I can't click any other tools, my mouse doesn't react.

I closed and opened Blender so many times and it didn't change. Also, uninstalled and reinstalled but didn't change.

Seems like if I don't go into *Edit Mode* other functions are working.

My blender is the latest 3.0
I'm using macOS Monterey version12.1

Comment: can u provide blend file pls? maybe you pressed some weird key combi ;)

Comment: @Chris um where can I see it?

Comment: thank you for the correction

Comment: you can use for example https://blend-exchange.com/ , put your blend file in and use this question URL, then follow further instructions

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=5KbJknWQ" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/5KbJknWQ/) is this working?

Comment: I  am sorry ,I don`t see any problem I can rotate the view, select tools etc. in edit mode

Comment: that is so weird... would my laptop have a problem?

Comment: my keys even don't work I can only select/deselect the edges

Comment: Fine here too under Windows.

Comment: Works here as well, maybe some other apple user will be able to see what is going on if they have similar machine but it means that problem is related to your mac(HW or SW), rather than to blender itself

Comment: fine here on macbook too

Comment: Thank you for all of you trying to help it's solved !!!

Comment: @blue don't add "Solved" to the header. Instead, mark the answer as accepted. This will add green color to the question list and every one will know that it has been solved. This is how the website works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some useful information you may find at the bottom of the window. This tells you that you may confirm selection by pressing Enter or cancel by pressing some special mac key:

[image]

Comment: it got back to the first cube screen

Comment: you just gotta open your goldfish file again

Comment: still doesn't change :(

Comment: Does all work with the first cube screen?

Comment: oh I just realised it gets stuck when only I used c key (also for a cube)

Comment: Oh! ok. Then press Enter or Right Mouse Button

Comment: OHHHH YOU ARE A GENIUS

Comment: I also asked to teachers in my school (supposed to know about Blenders) they couldn't figure out haha